# C#: How to rewrite it without "copy/paste" code

Tags: c#, delegates, copy-paste

I have 2 similar methods:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="domain"></param>
    /// <exception cref="DomainRecordNotFoundException">Throw when the dns record is not found in Office365</exception>
    /// <exception cref="DomainNotFoundException">Throw when domain is not added to Office365</exception>
    /// <exception cref="UnknownException">Unknown exception from Microsoft Graph</exception>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<string> GetMxRecordForDomainAsync(string domain)
    {
        try
        {
            var records = await _graphClient.Domains[domain].ServiceConfigurationRecords.Request().GetAsync();
            string mxRecord = String.Empty;

            foreach (var record in records)
            {
                if (record.RecordType == "Mx")
                {
                    mxRecord = ((Microsoft.Graph.DomainDnsMxRecord)record).MailExchange;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mxRecord))
                throw new DomainRecordNotFoundException(DomainRegistrationCore.Models.DomainRecordType.MX);

            return mxRecord;
        }
        catch (ServiceException graphEx)
        {
            if (graphEx.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                throw new DomainNotFoundException();
            }

            throw new UnknownException(graphEx.StatusCode, graphEx.Error.Message);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="domain"></param>
    /// <exception cref="DomainRecordNotFoundException">Throw when the dns record is not found in Office365</exception>
    /// <exception cref="DomainNotFoundException">Throw when domain is not added to Office365</exception>
    /// <exception cref="UnknownException">Unknown exception from Microsoft Graph</exception>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<string> GetVerificationRecordForDomainAsync(string domain)
    {
        try
        {
            var records = (await _graphClient.Domains[domain].VerificationDnsRecords.Request().GetAsync());
            string verificationText = String.Empty;

            foreach (var record in records)
            {
                if (record.RecordType == "Txt")
                {
                    verificationText = ((Microsoft.Graph.DomainDnsTxtRecord)record).Text;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(verificationText))
                throw new DomainRecordNotFoundException(DomainRegistrationCore.Models.DomainRecordType.TXT);

            return verificationText;
        }
        catch (ServiceException graphEx)
        {
            if (graphEx.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                throw new DomainNotFoundException();
            }

            throw new UnknownException(graphEx.StatusCode, graphEx.Error.Message);
        }
    }
```

as we can see, these 2 methods differ only this part:

```
        foreach (var record in records)
        {
            if (record.RecordType == **RECORD**)
            {
                mxRecord = ((**TYPE_OF_RECORD**)record).MailExchange;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mxRecord))
            throw new DomainRecordNotFoundException(**RECORD**);
```

other parts are the same. I want to rewrite it for one common method, but don't understand how. I assume, that I can do it with `Func<>` or `Action<>`

Comment: Pass the RecordType to your method and make conditions by it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First define common interface

```
public interface IExtractor
{
    string RecordType { get; }
    string ErrorMessage { get; }
    string GetValue(object record);
}
```

Next create implementations

```
class MxRecordExtractor : IExtractor
{
    public string RecordType => "Mx";

    public string ErrorMessage => DomainRegistrationCore.Models.DomainRecordType.MX;

    public string GetValue(object record)
    {
        return ((Microsoft.Graph.DomainDnsMxRecord)record).MailExchange;
    }
}

class VerificationRecordExtractor : IExtractor
{
    public string RecordType => "Txt";

    public string ErrorMessage => DomainRegistrationCore.Models.DomainRecordType.TXT;

    public string GetValue(object record)
    {
        return ((Microsoft.Graph.DomainDnsTxtRecord)record).Text;
    }
}
```

Later create private abstracted version of method:

```
private async Task<string> ExtractForDomainAsync(string domain, IExtractor extractor)
{
    try
    {
        var records = (await _graphClient.Domains[domain].VerificationDnsRecords.Request().GetAsync());
        string extractedValue = String.Empty;

        foreach (var record in records)
        {
            if (record.RecordType == extractor.RecordType)
            {
                extractedValue = extractor.GetValue(record);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(extractedValue))
            throw new DomainRecordNotFoundException(extractor.ErrorMessage);

        return extractedValue;
    }
    catch (ServiceException graphEx)
    {
        if (graphEx.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            throw new DomainNotFoundException();
        }

        throw new UnknownException(graphEx.StatusCode, graphEx.Error.Message);
    }
}
```

Finally modify existing methods to use our common method:

```
public Task<string> GetMxRecordForDomainAsync(string domain)
{
    return ExtractForDomainAsync(domain,  new MxRecordExtractor());
}

public Task<string> GetVerificationRecordForDomainAsync(string domain)
{
    return ExtractForDomainAsync(domain, new VerificationRecordExtractor());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could first write down a simplified schema for methods and analyze their structure:

```
Method1(domain)
  some stuff...
  foreach if(c1) res = (Type1)smth
  if (res == null) throw ex(errMsg1)

Method2(domain)
  some stuff...
  foreach if(c2) res = (Type2)smth
  if (res == null) throw ex(errMsg2)
```

So what each function has?

- Common code (including foreach loop)
- Some specific condition in 'if' statement
- Specific type to which we cast the result to
- Specific error message that we use for exception we throw in case when result is null or empty

How can we fulfill these conditions and create one function?

- For number one in our list we don't need anything
- For second condition we can pass argument which we then use in
  'if' condition.
- For third we can either use generics and pass the type as type
  parameter or cast result to `dynamic`
- Error message once again we can accept as parameter

So a simplified structure of a new method might look like:

```
Method3<TDomainType>(domain, recordTypeToCheck, errorMsg)
  some stuff...
  foreach if(record.RecordType == recordTypeToCheck) res = (TDomainType)smth
  if (res == null) throw ex with errorMsg
```

Comment: If we have one more type then our foreach would be with one more if like: `foreach if(record.RecordType == recordTypeToCheck) res = (TDomainType)smth else if....`